# Best way to implement referral technique/app invitation in android?

Tags: java, android, sdk, referrals

I have to implement referral concept in my app ie ,

The campaigner/user will tell some one to install the app.and if he accepting and installing the app from play store the campaigner/user will get some rewards..

The referral intermediary apps might be Facebook,whatsapp,sms etc.

How i will implement this concept ? is there any sdk available which can be use in real time ?

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: I don't think it is possible to detect source from where you landed on PlayStore inside your app. you can use referral codes though.

Comment: If you have done this before please help me with the logic...how i can get the details of campaigner in real time when a user install and register after reffering ?

Comment: provide unique referral codes to your users and ask them to share these codes with people whom they want to refer. now when a person who is referred tries to register, have to enter the code provided to him/her.

Comment: The customer of my app do not really interested to bring any back-end/web services into the scene..i too imagined the logic what you mentioned.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might got your answer already but if anyone came across  this question wondering same thing.

you can use  these services

- [Firebase App invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/)
- [Facebook App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites)